# Delete all user's meta without knowing all the 'key'

Tags: multisite, mysql, user-meta, front-end

Trying to delete users from the frontend - which I currently have working. Previously, I was manually deleting the metadata when it was completed.

I was looking to see if it was possible to delete all associated to the now non-existent user ID.

I tried finding anything about looping the `delete_user_meta($user_id, *)` but couldn't with how to match the key.

I found this:

```
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID )
```

But is there then a way to have it get the `wp_` table prefix.

This is the way I am deleting from the frontend after the $_POST and validation:

```
if( $mb_user_delete ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
    $user_delete_id = wp_delete_user( $user_id );

    if( !is_wp_error($user_delete_id) ) {
        delete_user_meta( $user_id, '' );
        die( 'User has been successfully deleted' );
    } else {
        die( $user_delete_id->get_error_message() );            
    }
}
```

Comment: "But is there then a way to have it get the wp_ table prefix." - yes, you can get the prefix or the complete table names from the $wpdb object.

Comment: You can get all metadata keys that exist for a user with [`get_metadata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata). But I'd be surprised if you needed to: I'd have expected wp_usermeta to FKR back to the user table. If the user still exists there but is flagged deleted why do you need to delete the metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to find and delete user meta explicitly, because when you remove a WordPress user using `wp_delete_user()`, it deletes user and, **Posts and all meta is also be deleted that are for that User ID.**.

[**Documentation**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_user/)

Comment: thank you! didn't realise it was that way - makes it easier